# Understanding the property of complementhood

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

In the following sentence:

> They can both speak French.

How can *French* be the complement of the V-bar *speak French*?

I have the following definition of the complement:

> A constituent X is the complement of a head H if X and H are sisters and the mother of X is a projection of H.

To begin with, I don't see how *French* and *speak French* are sisters. Isn't *French* the daughter of *speak French*?

Comment: It's all about 'licensing'. Matthews in The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Linguistics defines it as "A syntactic element seen as completing the construction of another element’ (BillJ - the syntactic concept construction is preferable to the semantic concept meaning). He goes on to say, more specifically, that it applies to elements which are within the valency of a verb or other lexical unit. And  his entry for `valency’ is: `The range of syntactic elements either required or specifically permitted by a verb or other lexical unit’ – which is equivalent to licensing.

Comment: Direct objects are complements. "French" is the direct object of "speak", which licenses it, and hence must be a complement. But "French" is not licensed by "sneeze, so *"They can sneeze French" is ungrammatical.

Comment: @BillJ Okay, if I take your definition then it makes sense that French is a complement, but I can't see how this definition I have makes sense in this example. Both the example and the definition are from Radford's Syntactic Theory and the Structure of English.

Comment: Nor can I! My definition comes from general purpose grammar, not theoretical grammar.

Comment: @BillJ That's somewhat comforting haha. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It isn't. It's the Complement of the verb *speak* and both it and the verb *speak* are daughters of the v-bar. *Speak* is the head and *French* the Complement (Direct Object)

Comment: @Araucaria This is from Radford's Syntactic Theory and the Structure of English:  [...] *French* is the complement of *speak*, since the relevant V and N nodes are sisters, and the mother of N is a V-bar constituent *speak French* which is a projection of the verb *speak*; and, by extension we might say that *French* is also the complement of the V-bar *speak French*, and of the VP *both speak French*.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me ... (That doesn't necessarily mean very much though).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me because there are phrase rules given, none which allow for a phrase to be a complement of a phrase that includes it. The V-bar, for example isn't  sister of *French*. Sounds completely confusing.